# Simple query related to $\cos(\theta)$ function

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I want to find the range of $\theta$ for which we have $$x-b\cos(\theta)<0$$ where $x<b$ and $b$ is a constant and both can have only positive values. I can write the above inequality as follows $$\arccos\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)<\theta.$$ But $\theta=0$ does not come out in the answer although $\theta=0$ can obeys the first inequality. Where am I wrong in this?

Comment: Notice that $\arccos$ is decreasing function, hence your inequality is inverted.

Comment: @Galc127 so it means whenever we apply decreasing function on both sided the equality will be inverted? Or it is just for this case?

Comment: Not always, when both sides are non-negative.

Comment: @Galc127 ok. Thank you for your comments.